# History saving thread error when trying to open Pandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed IPython on a remote desktop at work. I had to create a shortcut on my desktop to connect to IPython because the remote desktop does not have internet access. I am able to successfully open the IPython notebook. However, when I try to import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get this error that I have never seen before

```
The history saving thread hit an unexpected error (OperationalError('database or disk is full',)).History will not be written to the database.
```

Does this error relate to how it was installed on the remote desktop?

Comment: I think the error message `database or disk is full` is pretty explicit. There isn't enough space on the machine where IPython is running to store history related to importing pandas.

Comment: @BoarGules The slight mystery occurs when you know your disc is not actually full, so you have to figure out what IS "full". This is what's happening to me right now, though the partition I'm using is only 4 GiB (out of 80) AWAY from being full. (Also, I'm not using pandas or Jupyter or a remote desktop, but rather Debian command line ipython3 natively on my MX linux laptop.) I haven't noticed anything it's actually stopped doing after this error, though, so I may just ignore it.

Comment: I suspect based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629390/where-is-the-history-file-for-ipython and an sqlite3 error I saw on the command line that it is the "~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite" file, which I found, which is "full", though I don't think I saw any error explicitly mentioned that file. (They're no longer in my terminal's scroll-up history, so I can't check.)

Comment: Actually, now when I restart ipython3 I see it very explicitly mentions first ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite, and then usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/history.py several times. The final part of the traceback (the actual error) is "sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full", though I got an error exactly like the original posts the first time, just randomly after I typed some command into the ipython3 interactive shell (the first command after the database filled up I guess).

Comment: My usr and home directory are both on the same not-quite-full hard drive partition though, so I can only guess that the sql file must have some maximum size it's allowed to reach, and I just need to clear it out somehow.

Comment: Actually, Firefox is now complaining it doesn't have enough space to download a 200 kB pdf, so I maybe it actually is my hard drive and there's just more than one way to estimate how much space I have left for some reason (maybe some applications have a buffer). I know some on my Android phone do (very annoying ones).

Answer (score 4):

I suffered from this problem for a long time. My dirty fix was to simply restart the kernel and go about my work. However, I did find a way which eliminated it for good. This question seems to have mixed answers for different users. I'll try to list all based on answers elsewhere (all links at the end).

So the issue seems to be because of a certain `nbsignatures.db` file. And we need to simply remove it to solve the issue. You may find the file here in any one of the locations:

1. ~/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db (I found mine here)
2. ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/nbsignatures.db
3. ~/Library/Jupyter/nbsignatures.db

All links:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9293
[IPython Notebook error: Error loading notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960020/ipython-notebook-error-error-loading-notebook)