# Where is the history file for ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I can not determine where the ipython is storing its history.

a. There is no ~/.pythonhistory:

```
12:49:00/dashboards $ll ~/.py*
ls: /Users/steve/.py*: No such file or directory
```

b. Nothing special in the python startup file:

```
12:49:07/dashboards $echo $PYTHONSTARTUP
/shared/.pythonstartup
12:49:43/dashboards $cat /shared/.pythonstartup
import rlcompleter
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

c. BUT: i do have plenty of history available in ipython when I start it up.

So where is that history being stored?

*UPDATE*   the answer from @Stefano led the correct way: here is the actual path

```
13:30:05/shared $ll ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  372736 Jun  3 12:48 /Users/steve/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

IPython history is stored in a SQLite database located in the profile directory. By default:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

Older versions (1.x) stored profile data in `~/.config/ipython`, at least on platforms conforming to [XDG basedir specs](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) (i.e. most Linux distributions).

Anyway, you can locate the profile directory with:

```
$ ipython locate profile default
```

Notice that the history database is shared between IPython and IPython3, if both are installed.

Comment: Additionally, the table name is `history`. This would allow you for instance to search this database using sqlite3.

Comment: How to set the location of this file separate from profile?

Answer (score 69):

If you want your IPython history in a plain-text file, you can export it yourself.

```
%history -g -f filename
```

Comment: I find no `-g` works well for me, too. What does `-g` do?

Comment: Without `-g` it exports the history for the current session. With `-g` it exports history for all sessions.  The only documentation I found for `-g` is by typing `%quickref` in to an IPython shell.