# Error loading IPython Jupyter notebook:

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, malformed, diskimage

I have an error while loading IPython Jupyter notebook. Also errors occur on the shell. Is there anyone who could help me for solving these errors?

---

Errors which occur on the shell:

```
Unhandled error in API request
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

Error loading Jupyter notebook:

```
An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. 
This version can load notebook formats v4 or earlier. See the server log for details.
```

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a problem with your history database. Find your `history.sqlite`. It should be here:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

Rename or remove it and try to start the notebook server again.

Comment: I get a "Permission denied" warning when I entered your offered comment. What should I do? Thanks. @MikeMüller

Comment: Did you stop all of your notebook servers before renaming/removing the file?

Comment: In case someone's wondering, I used `ipython locate profile default` command as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629448/3679900) for locating the `history.sqlite` file