# Jupyter Notebook didn't save for over a day. How can I recover lost work?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook

I've lost a day's work in Jupyter Notebook because it didn't autosave. As I was working, I would click on `File` > `Save and Checkpoint` to be safe. I closed the notebook when I finished working and when I tried reopening it, I see that essentially all my work is gone and it says `Last Checkpoint: a day ago (autosaved)` next to the filename. I now realize that I had been working for a long time on the notebook with an orange box with some kind of error message. I'm sorry that I can't remember the specific message right now, but I think it was something involving `POS` or `POST` or `POSIT` ...?. I saw `Trusted` next to the error message, so I must've thought things were OK.

I tried opening the `filename-checkpoint.ipynb` file within the `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder but it's blank. I looked up a possible solution on [Recovering from a Jupyter Disaster](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/recovering-from-a-jupyter-disaster-27401677aeeb), but it requires SQL, which I don't know. Is there any hope for recovering my work? I realize that this is probably a rookie mistake, but I'm pretty new at this.

Thanks

PS: I'm running Python3 on MacOS

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Hope you've already found how to recover lost work from Jupyter notebook work. If not, try the following:

- Go to Anaconda Navigator (the green circle!)
- Launch a Jupyter Lab
- In Jupyter Lab, open a Terminal window
- Launch iPython in the terminal by typing ipython and hitting enter
- Hit Up arrow
- All your code are stored in history and each cell compilation that you would've done in the past shows up there.
- Copy+Paste it back to a new Jupyter notebook and you are ready to go again!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was a while back, so the code history would be really long between now and then. I was able to reconstruct my work though. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You saved me a day of work

Comment: You can also do it from a regular ipython shell, then you can copy paste (with these annoying ... in front of it. You can use e.g. vim to get rid of those.)

Comment: Thanks , could not get everything, but recovered some fraction of work.

Comment: You can copy-paste from this terminal by selecting with mouse, holding shift and right clicking to get the menu.

Comment: Praise be to you! Saved me a week of work

Comment: 5 days of work here..... thank you SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! do your GIT guys girls... make time even if there isnt any...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have Anaconda Navigator you can do access the same data the manual way:

1. open a new ipython terminal
2. type `%history -g -f history.txt`

This will output the entire history of edits which are saved in history.sqlite in your IPython profile folder. You can scroll down to the bottom to find your most recent edits.

You can also just explore the `history.sqlite` directly, which is located in your IPython profile. The profile should be inside `.ipython` in your user directory (windows and linux).

[Thanks to Christian Long's answer on another question for providing this info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415188/10023732)

Comment: Also looking at the documentation I think there might be a way to filter by date or session id, not entirely sure.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to copy/paste.
After running `terminal` and `ipython`, page_up yo code you want. Click right button on a mouse, then Watch the elements code. Now you can select code, copy and paste it.