# IPython Notebook error: Error loading notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Within the past few minutes, I have not been able to access any of the `.ipynb` files previously created with Python3.4. I go to the subdirectory with these files, enter

```
ipython3 notebook
```

When I open a "New" notebook, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled1.ipynb database disk image is malformed
```

I cannot open old notebooks either. I get the error:

```
An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version can load notebook formats v4 or earlier. See the server log for details.
```

and within the Terminal, it states

```
kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 00:30:22.352 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 460, in get
        value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
    KeyError: 'db'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8294

Comment: Don't forget to restart!

Comment: @Crt Tried that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search for `nbsignatures.db`. It should be either here:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/security/nbsignatures.db
```

or here:

```
 ~/Library/Jupyter/nbsignatures.db
```

The `~` stands for you home directory.

Move this file this to a temporary directory.

Restart your IPython Notebook server.

Comment: Removing the `nbsignatures.db` file solved the problem, i.e. `rm  ~/Library/Jupyter/nbsignatures.db`

Answer (score 16):

This won't be the issue for everyone, but I got the below error message because the disk was actually full.

```
An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version can load notebook formats v4 or earlier. See the server log for details.
```

Comment: me too, my home directory is full in the Linux server

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had the same issue, my C drive was full. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

remove ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite

this helps for me.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks! 

I was getting a slightly different error than OP, one which did not include a specific version number: "An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version can load notebook formats or earlier. See the server log for details."

Comment: This worked for me with Jupyter for vs code extension. It was generating multiple versions of history.sqlite file.

extension: v2022.2.1030672458 Mac: OS 10.15.7 Python: 3.9.7. 

Error message: "The history saving thread hit an unexpected error (OperationalError('attempt to write a readonly database')).History will not be written to the database."

Answer (score 5):

Since I couldn't find any of the files mentioned in the other answers, I looked for another solution and found this one to work for me:

> I solved this problem by changing the ownership of the ~/.local/share/jupyter directory from root to user.

from https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8997

Comment: I had a similar issue. But because the value of the environment variable `XDG_DATA_HOME` was malformed as `/.local/share`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, my nbsignatures.db was here, after removing it it can operate normally.

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db
```

Remember to restart your jupyter notebook server. I restarted several times for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Non of the other answers helped in my case.

In the end I simply copied my notebook and renamed the copy.
The copy didn't have the error.

Answer (score 0):

First run the following in the terminal:

`sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root`

Then some URL will appear in the terminal, something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=f2704ecba4c88716337f33e79e13335380e25382603afb80
```

Finally, copy and paste this URL in a new tab in your browser. Then the jupyter notebook will open in a new tab.