# UnicodeEncodeError : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' while saving and accessing Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Django(Python 2.7) application with IPython notebook in a docker container and for some notebook, while accessing I am getting Error of **An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook** when I check logs it's showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1415, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 230, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
    path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 433, in get
    model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 392, in _notebook_model
    self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 503, in mark_trusted_cells
    trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 438, in check_signature
    signature = self.compute_signature(nb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 417, in compute_signature
    for b in yield_everything(nb):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 272, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 276, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(element):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 272, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 276, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(element):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 272, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 272, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 276, in yield_everything
    for b in yield_everything(element):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 281, in yield_everything
    yield str(obj).encode('utf8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

[image: Error Image: An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook]

The same problem is happening when I am saving a file with the shape of the data frame Row X column problem was with the parsing of X(u'\xd7') Unicode.

Tried changing sys encoding noting happened

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: Did you see this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960020/ipython-notebook-error-error-loading-notebook

Comment: Try `latin1` ? Though I doubt it will help.

Comment: Thankyou @hamedbaziyad but the problem is different then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960020/ipython-notebook-error-error-loading-notebook

Comment: Thankyou @CeliusStingher but the problem is still same

Comment: what version of tornado, nbformat, ipython are you using?

Comment: I had a similar problem running Jupyter inside docker container on GCS and ssh-ing with port forwarding. In my case, the problem was with locale settings on the container - it could not decode characters that my browser was producing while running the notebook and would fail to save the running notebook. You may want to look into these threads in case you have similar issues: https://github.com/fastai/fastprogress/issues/21

Comment: Hi @marke I am using ipython==5.3.0, ipython-genutils==0.2.0, nbformat==5.0.3, tornado==4.2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbformat==5.0.x requires python 3.5+

> Starting with 5.0, nbformat is now Python 3 only (>= 3.5)

https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id2