# Unexpected error while saving Jupyter Notebook: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 1885: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ascii, jupyter

While saving my Jupyter Notebook, I am getting the following error:

> Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 1885: ordinal not in range(128)

This is only happening with one of the cells - namely, the second one in the attached image.
[image]

Comment: best to save scripts/files instead of notebooks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' while saving and accessing Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841253/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xd7-while-saving-a)

Comment: @techytushar Unfortunately not; I saw that post earlier, but I already installed Python 3.9 and am using a Python 3 kernel.