# 'ascii' codec can't encode character - jupyter notebook python 3.9

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i know this has brought up quite a few times, but I'm actually having quite a funky issue. I am trying to run a python 3.9 notebook, but even if i don't write anything in the cells, i get an error message about encoding. In the past, i have had this issue with other versions of python, but to simply save the notebook, i would 'clear cells' then save it from there. but in python 3.9, i cant even do that.

[image]

I have tried encoding with creating a jupyter_notebook_config.py script in my home folder that contains:

[image]

but it still fails!

when i check the encoding of notebooks i have created, they are all like this:
[image]

Comment: `f.read().decode('utf8')` how about that

Comment: enforce opening in utf8 or make sure file has BOM , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-with-bom

Comment: @ykhrustalev but i am not even trying to open a file, its simply the notebook itself which is encoded in ascii and not utf8

Comment: try adding `open(..., encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Try opening with notepad and then save as with encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: @MichaelCao maybe not a bad idea. how would i set the encoding in python 3.9 ?

Comment: @ykhrustalev but my aim isn't to open a file.. its just the general notebook encoding

Comment: you need to show the error you have, so far, you state that encoding is the problem, but don't show us the problem

Comment: in my 2nd image, i show an 'unexpected error while saving' - this is the only thing that i see.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might have happened [once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463582/unexpected-error-while-saving-jupyter-notebook-ascii-codec-cant-encode-chara), but it never got resolved.

Mine has absolutely no trouble reading and writing UTF-8 `.ipynb` files.  The character it's complaining about is the `“` "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK" character, but I'd imagine it could be any character.

Can you check the log window/file for Jupyter Notebook (the NotebookApp stuff) to see if there's a stack trace?  I only see [two](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/6fdc8d38e516b1829f3a26c6ad996c9eab742a86/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py#L508) [places](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/6fdc8d38e516b1829f3a26c6ad996c9eab742a86/notebook/services/contents/largefilemanager.py#L35) where that particular error message might get thrown.  There also aren't that many places where `ascii` appears in the code, and most of them involve base64 strings that should be ASCII anyway.